# Table population with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to populate a table in HTML with data from a JSON array using JavaScript. My code is given below:

```
<head>
        <title>Employee page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div id="tableData"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var json_arr = {{ data_arr|safe }};
            var tableData = '<table>';
            tableData += '<th>' + "Serial no." + '</th>';
            tableData += '<th>' + "Name" + '</th>';
            tableData += '<th>' + "Age" + '</th>';
            for (var i=0;i<json_arr.length;i++){
                alert("Hello world!!");
                var obj = json_arr[i];
                alert(obj.id);
                tableData += '<tr>';
                tableData += '<td>' + odj.id + '</td>';
                tableData += '<td>' + odj.name + '</td>';
                tableData += '<td>' + obj.age + '</td>';
                tableData += '</tr>';
            }
            tableData += '</table>';
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tableData;
            $('#tableData').html(tableData);
        </script>
    </body>
```

The JSON data is coming to the JS properly. The problem in the loop is in the line "tableData += '' + odj.id + '';" (maybe thereafter as well). I don't know how to fix it. No table is appearing in the HTML. Can someone please suggest how to fix this or at least an alternate way to do this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What is `json_arr = {{ data_arr|safe }}` ?

Comment: It removes u' tags added to JSON by Python's json.loads()

Comment: what is odj  when you say odj.id & odj.name ? typo for  "obj" ?

Comment: thank you so much...I am very sorry I asked such a stupid question..!

Comment: np . Maybe you could consider change text-editor / IDE :)